# Create an ReportServer folder within another ReportServer folder

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create two RS folder with PowerShell. the first folder is created successfully but not the second one. basically, i am creating a folder within a folder.

```
$ReportServerUri = "http://localhost/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx?wsdl"
$global:proxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $ReportServerUri -UseDefaultCredential

$type = $Proxy.GetType().Namespace
$datatype = ($type + '.Property')

$property = New-Object ($datatype);
$property.Name = "NewFolder"
$property.Value = "NewFolder"

$numproperties = 1
$properties = New-Object ($datatype + '[]')$numproperties 
$properties[0] = $property;

$proxy.CreateFolder("Test", "/", $properties);
$proxy.CreateFolder("Test/Test2", "/", $properties);
```

Comment: So what's the error?

Comment: There's a pretty well maintained PowerShell module for interacting with Reporting Services that you might want to look at: https://github.com/Microsoft/ReportingServicesTools. I believe the `New-RsFolder` cmdlet of the module might be what you need.

Comment: hi gvee. i'm getting the below error
Exception calling "CreateFolder" with "3" argument(s): "The name of the item
'Test/Test2' is not valid. The name must be less than 260 characters long. The
name must not start with a slash character or contain a reserved character.
Other restrictions apply. For more information on valid item names, see
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=398858. --->

Answer (score 3):

```
$proxy.CreateFolder("Test/Test2", "/", $properties);
```

If you look at [TechNet for CreateFolder()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010.createfolder?view=sqlserver-2016) you will see you are not populating the root folder parameter correctly. That is what the second parameter is for. Slash is probably an illegal character for a folder name.

```
$proxy.CreateFolder("Test2", "/Test", $properties);
```

Should work.